# Select or Count when one employee (CI_NUM) produces a record at more than one facility (FAC_NUM)

Tags: ms-access

I am looking to query when one employee (field `CI_NUM` format str) produces a record at more than one facility (field `FAC_NUM` format str) within 15 minutes (field `INSP_DTE` format Date/Time appears as m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM) See below sample data. There is one instance of what I am looking for in the sample see field `CI_NUM` value `ZT83`. The results could be in the form of a count of instances or list of records related to instances.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           INSP_DTE            |       CI_NUM       |      FAC_NUM       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:32:07 PM | 4ER9               | 7114626            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:31:27 PM | 16QC               | 7121382            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:31:14 PM | 2RG8               | 7129540            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:29:18 PM | 52RH               | 7129053            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:29:10 PM | 66VE               | 7113253            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:29:03 PM | T053               | 7029897            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:28:48 PM | 28BQ               | 7120513            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:28:42 PM | ZT83               | 7044319            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:28:11 PM | ZT83               | 7011322            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:27:26 PM | YR50               | 7065726            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:25:01 PM | 72WP               | 7087298            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:24:48 PM | 41DB               | 7121434            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:22:42 PM | 4XM5               | 7129938            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:21:20 PM | 7PF2               | 7010482            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:20:09 PM | 59MP               | 7077037            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:16:59 PM | YR50               | 7065726            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:16:58 PM | 9FL1               | 6411318            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:16:54 PM | 71AF               | 7124682            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          3/29/2023 8:16:24 PM | 15KF               | 7130471            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been able to determine what employees have produced records at more than one facility with two select queries. The first groups by CI_NUM and FAC_NUM and second uses the first to count how many times CI_NUM appears in the first. I am stuck on where and how to update the criteria to limit results to a specific timeframe (15 minutes/1 hour/1 day), but not from a fixed date. Instead from the previous record produced by a given employee. Or maybe some use of a composite primary key could help? I am stumped.

Comment: Although data looks a little different, this is essentially a repeat of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75619876/ms-access-show-count-when-one-select-field-value-follows-another-field-value-wit

Comment: Yes, but not answered and this question was legitimately borne from another task requested of me with many similarities. So I ask more or less the same question again because if this question, borne from another task, is answered it will help me achieve two tasks. Worst case scenario I am right where I began and the community still can't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

per the comments follow this example: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

for instance:

```
SELECT Test.INSP_DTE, Test.CI_NUM, Test.FAC_NUM, (SELECT top 1 DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) FROM Test AS dupe WHERE (Test.[CI_NUM] = dupe.CI_NUM)  AND (Test.[INSP_DTE] < dupe.INSP_DTE) ) AS SignIn2
FROM Test
ORDER BY Test.INSP_DTE;
```

In the query Designer this sql looks like:

[image]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                INSP_DTE                |         CI_NUM          |      FAC_NUM       |            SignIn2            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:16:24 PM | 15KF                    |            7130471 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:16:54 PM | 71AF                    |            7124682 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:16:58 PM | 9FL1                    |            6411318 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:16:59 PM | YR50                    |            7065726 |                            11 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:20:09 PM | 59MP                    |            7077037 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:21:20 PM | 7PF2                    |            7010482 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:22:42 PM | 4XM5                    |            7129938 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:24:48 PM | 41DB                    |            7121434 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:25:01 PM | 72WP                    |            7087298 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:27:26 PM | YR50                    |            7065726 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:28:11 PM | ZT83                    |            7011322 |                             0 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:28:42 PM | ZT83                    |            7044319 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:28:48 PM | 28BQ                    |            7120513 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:29:03 PM | T053                    |            7029897 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:29:10 PM | 66VE                    |            7113253 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:29:18 PM | 52RH                    |            7129053 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:31:14 PM | 2RG8                    |            7129540 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:31:27 PM | 16QC                    |            7121382 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                   3/29/2023 8:32:07 PM | 4ER9                    |            7114626 |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Signin2** is just a calculated field.  we can set a calculated field to a query by wrapping the query in parentheses.

**Top 1** is easy to add in the sql pane and a tricky right click in the designer which you may have to google.  Top 1 is not actually needed for the sample data.

**(SELECT top 1 DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE)** : gets the difference in minutes between the two dates if both exist

**WHERE (Test.[CI_NUM] = dupe.CI_NUM)  AND (Test.[INSP_DTE] < dupe.INSP_DTE)** this is just a normal where clause that looks for records with the same CI_NUM but higher Test.INSP_DTE.  This is where you can add restrictions like

```
' limit to records within 1 to 30 minutes
SignIn2: (SELECT top 1 DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) FROM Test AS dupe WHERE (Test.[CI_NUM] = dupe.CI_NUM)  AND (DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) between  1 and 30))

' 0 had subtle issues like not returning null so had to do the long way:

SELECT Test.INSP_DTE, Test.CI_NUM, Test.FAC_NUM, (SELECT top 1 DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) FROM Test AS dupe WHERE ((Test.[CI_NUM] = dupe.CI_NUM)  AND (DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) >0) AND (Test.[CI_NUM] = dupe.CI_NUM)  AND (DateDiff("n",Test.[INSP_DTE], dupe.INSP_DTE) <30)) ) AS SignIn2
FROM Test
ORDER BY Test.INSP_DTE;
```

Comment: Thanks let me review this. I may not reply for a day or two